# How to add a value under a specific heading in a dataframe as part of a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, append

Let's say i created a dataframe as follows:

```
headings = {'A'=[],'B'=[]}
data = pd.DataFrame(headings)
```

Then as part of a for loop, the output of a function adds values to the data frame but only under 'B':

```
order=[1,2,3,4]

for x in order:
    output = function(x)
    data = data.append(output)
```

Which produce this:

```
     A   B
0    Nan 23
1    Nan 24
2    Nan 26
3    Nan 27
```

I want to add x itself under 'A' as part of the for loop so the output looks like this

```
    A   B
0   1   23
1   2   24
2   3   26
3   4   27
```

I cant reveal the actual function/data as its sensitive but let me know if you need further info

Comment: `data['A'] = order`

Comment: I tried data['A'] = order in the for loop but i get an error "ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (1)". I also tried data['A']=order before the loop and it added the values above the the output values on seperate rows

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replace na with value of interest

> ```
> for x in order:
>     output = function(x)
>     data = data.append(output)
>     data.fillna(value=x,inplace=True) #inplace replaces the original dataframe
> ```